# How to automatically turn off "hlsearch" after I'm done searching?

Tags: search, highlight

I love the "hlsearch" setting, but after I'm done searching, I find it obnoxious. Especially if I search for something that has a lot of matches. I know that I can turn this off with

```
:set nohlsearch
```

But this takes a whole 16 keystrokes, and even more annoyingly, I have to turn it back on for my next search with

```
:set hlsearch
```

Is there a way I can have hlsearch automatically toggle on when I start searching, and off when I am done searching? For example, if I enter insert mode, or modify the text, have hlsearch turn off without any additional keystrokes?

Comment: Define automatically.

Comment: @Antony As in, if I'm making edits, or in insert mode, it will turn off without me needing to press any buttons. If I start searching with `/` or `?`, or if I press `n` or `N`, it will turn on without me needing to press any more buttons.

Comment: Oh and define "done" searching

Comment: `:nno <BS> :set hls!\|set hls?<CR>` -- one line, one keypress, state feedback, and doesn't try to second-guess when you may or may not want highlighting. Sometimes I want highlighting left on the screen when editing. Sometimes I don't, e.g. using `/` as a motion with an operator.

Comment: `nnoremap <M-\>  :set hlsearch!<CR><Bar>:echo 'hlsearch: ' . ['Off', 'On'][&hlsearch]<CR>`

Comment: I have ``set hlsearch`` as well as ``nmap <silent> <C-N> :silent noh<CR>`` in my vimrc. This way, I always get highlighted search and pressing CTRL-n simply removes the highlights (of the last search). It is actually handy to disable highlights manually once you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 42):

There is a much more convenient way. Rather than using

```
:set nohlsearch
```

which actually turns the hlsearch setting off, use

```
:nohls
```

This will only turn hlsearch off until you search again. From `:help nohls`

```
                 *'hlsearch'* *'hls'* *'nohlsearch'* *'nohls'*
'hlsearch' 'hls'    boolean (default off)
            global
            {not in Vi}
            {not available when compiled without the
            |+extra_search| feature}

    ...

    When you get bored looking at the highlighted matches, you can turn it
    off with |:nohlsearch|.  This does **not change the option value**, as
    soon as you use a search command, the highlighting comes back.
```

However, this solution isn't perfect, since you still have to type out `:nohls` which is pain to do after every search. You can get around this with a mapping, e.g.

```
nnoremap <esc><esc> :silent! nohls<cr>
```

But there is an even *better* solution! [haya14busa/incsearch.vim](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim). This is, at least in my opinion, an *essential* vim plugin. The main feature is that **all** search matches are highlighted in real time, as you are typing out your regex. For example:

[image]

However, a secondary feature that is also provided is the option to *immediately* toggle hlsearch on and off when you start/stop searching. To enable this feature, you will have to add

```
set hlsearch
let g:incsearch#auto_nohlsearch = 1
map n  <Plug>(incsearch-nohl-n)
map N  <Plug>(incsearch-nohl-N)
map *  <Plug>(incsearch-nohl-*)
map #  <Plug>(incsearch-nohl-#)
map g* <Plug>(incsearch-nohl-g*)
map g# <Plug>(incsearch-nohl-g#)
```

to your `.vimrc`.

If you have any other `n` mappings, you will have to turn these off. For example, I used to have

```
nnoremap n nzz
nnoremap N Nzz
```

These two mappings are not compatible with eachother!

Comment: Since you are doing a self answer i'd like to suggest that you also add another problem with `set hlsearch`.  If you have it defined in `vimrc` it will overwrite `:noh` every time you source the `vimrc`. To sort this out I have `if !&hlsearch | set hlsearch | endif` in my `vimrc`.  (And this is another problem that the plugin solves.)

Comment: Dunno, seems like a whole heap of code and config for not a lot of gain to me. In fact it makes the target of your incremental search harder to spot, making it less useful for quick navigation.

Comment: +1 for a great plugin answering question and doing a lot more!

Comment: `:noh` is an even shorter alias than `:nohls`

Comment: The features of this plugin have now been implemented into Vim. Do `set incsearch`

Answer (score 14):

[vim-cool](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool) is a simple plugin that does just this.

> Vim-cool disables search highlighting when you are done searching and
>   re-enables it when you search again.

It works *without remapping* by [using](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool/issues/9) the [`CursorMoved`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorMoved) and [`InsertEnter`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#InsertEnter) autocommands.

Comment: This technique (using autocommands) is way better than my answer, and I can't believe I didn't think of it when I wrote mine. Upvote.

Answer (score 7):

I have found it more intuitive to remap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> repaint to include `:nohls`:

```
nnoremap <C-L> :nohls<cr><C-L>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thank you for sharing your knowledge on what is admittedly an old question. High quality answers, as you might have noticed, generally come with some explanation of what the code is doing (this is especially helpful for newer vimmers who might land here without much knowledge). It can also be a good idea to the relevant `:help` sections!

Answer (score 6):

As you've [already noted in your own answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8742/343), it's far more efficient to turn off highlighting with the `:nohlsearch` command (which can be abbreviated to `:noh`) rather than turning off the entire feature and then turning it back on the next time you search.

If you want to switch off highlighting every time you use `i` to enter insert mode, you can create a simple mapping to do so:

```
:nnoremap i :noh<cr>i
```

It's left as an exercise for the reader to create similar mappings for other commands where they want highlighting switched off.

More recent versions of Vim have an `InsertEnter` autocommand which you might think could be used to easily create a cleaner implementation of switching off highlighting, but unfortunately, the [`:nohlsearch` command has no effect within an autocommand](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%3Anohlsearch). A possible workaround is instead to reset the search pattern when entering insert mode, but that obviously has side effects you may not desire:

```
augroup ClearSearch
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertEnter * let @/ = ''
augroup END
```

There is, however, a better technique, which is to use `feedkeys` from the autocommand. This is what the [vim-cool plugin](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool) mentioned in [Jon Parise's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13378/343) uses.

Answer (score 6):

I use `<Leader><Enter>` as a shortcut to `:noh`. (My leader is `,`, so it's pretty close)

This will turn off the highlights until your next search.

Answer (score 4):

It might sound stupid or naive, but what I do when I want to stop the highlighting is I search for a random string that (virtually certainly) is not present in the document. Something like this:

```
/skljdfhadhfs
```

Granted, it does take a few key strokes, but they are really random, so they can be typed in no time.

Comment: But this makes `n` and `N` no longer work, and also things like `:%s//something` or `:g//something`. It also clutters your search history

Comment: Yes, but my (probably incorrect) assumption is that since you don't need highlighting any more, you don't care about that particular search either. Cluttering the search history is a real issue, if one relies on it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that the following solution hasn't been posted:

```
augroup vimrc-incsearch-highlight
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineEnter /,\? :set hlsearch
  autocmd CmdlineLeave /,\? :set nohlsearch
augroup END
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! (Nice nick/avatar, lol.) It might be worth an [edit] explaining what this does/how it works

Comment: probably because the question predates the `CmdlineEnter` autocommand from Vim. Also, this comes right from the help section `:h 'incsearch'`

Answer (score 0):

I use `<Leader><Enter>` as a shortcut to `:hls` and have my leader set as space.

```
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
nmap <silent> <leader><Esc> :set hls!<cr>
```

After searching an item will be highlighted, to turn it off, hit `<Space><Esc>`.  And if you decide you want to redisplay the search results, hit `<Space><Esc>`.  The `hls!` means map this key binding to toggle the setting for `hls` (shorthand for `hlsearch`, i.e. search result highlighting) (so the `!` toggles the setting right before it).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little bit late, but there is a plugin called `is.vim`. Maybe it can be useful for someone, here is the link: https://vimawesome.com/plugin/is-vim

Answer (score 0):

Remark: turning off `hlsearch` (as in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22298/23502)) won't clear the search register.

It means that you can still jump to next/prev matches but with no highlights which could be annoying for some users as it was for me.

To clear the search register itself and the highlight in one command you may use:

```
:let @/ = ""
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I'm not sure I understand your answer. At first glance it looks more like a comment. Maybe could you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the confusion. It's a comment to remind that clearing the highlight on search matches won't clear the search register itself. it means that you can still jump to next/prev matches but with no highlights which could be annoying for some users as it was for me. Yet, to clear the search register itself and the highlight in one command you may use ` let @/ = "" `. BR

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe could you expand your answer to repeat the part of the answer you are refering to and to include your suggestion about the search register :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt, here. Thanks for being begginer friendly. Enjoy your day.

Comment: You are welcome :-) Since the sequence of answer vary with votes we try to encourage contributor to have answers that do not depend of other answers. I have slightly reformulated your answer in that direction, feel free to cancel my edition if it do not go in the direction you intended.

Comment: Thanks, it became way better.

Answer (score 0):

i use buildin vim function to solve it, just add this to `.vimrc`:

```
set hls
augroup clearhlsearch
 autocmd!
 autocmd InsertEnter,VimEnter,CursorHold * :let @/=""
augroup END
```

description:
set highlight search to enable `set hls`
make auto command group `clearhlsearch`, line 1 clear previous autocommand buffer with `autocmd!`, line 2 set search buffer to " "
when open vim `VimEnter` or exit from insert mode `InsertLeave`, or cursor not move `CursorHold` (it depend to set `updatetime`)
you can get my vim config in here [Wahyu's dotfile](https://gitlab.com/Phantasimay/dotfiles/-/blob/master/.vimrc)

Comment: Welcome to vim and thank you for answering. To make your solution anyone else's solution, you may want to edit and explain how it works, what it does and what makes it stand out from the many answers that are already here.

Comment: 'hls' is a global setting, so you don't need setlocal

Comment: @Friedrich probably you meant "To make your solution _different_ from anyone else's […]" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was actually replying to "[this] is my solution" in the sense of "it could be *my* solution as well (if anything convinced me to use it)". Reading my comment again: yes, it's awkward :) However, I hope people can understand that I was asking for a little bit of an explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Add this macro to your .vimrc

```
map #h :set hls!<CR>
```

This will allow you to toggle hilighting with #h

Comment: This is no different than James Affleck's answer.

Comment: Mine seems more concise.

Comment: Why is conciseness relevant?  The other post gives more information about what the parts of the command mean and this post provides no additional content.